# Extracting comments from XML file in Python

Tags: python, xml, pandas, information-extraction

I would like to extract the comment section of the XML file. The information that I would like to extract is found between the **Tag** and then within **Text** tag which is "EXAMPLE".

The structure of the XML file looks below.

```
<Boxes>

  <Box Id="3" ZIndex="13">
      <Shape>Rectangle</Shape>
      <Brush Id="0" />
      <Pen>
        <Color>#FF000000</Color>

      </Pen>
      <Tag>&lt;?xml version="1.0"?&gt;
&lt;PFDComment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;
  &lt;Text&gt;**EXAMPLE** &lt;/Text&gt;

&lt;/PFDComment&gt;</Tag>
  </Box>

</Boxes>
```

I tried it something below but couldn't get the information that I want.

```
def read_cooments(xml):
    tree = lxml.etree.parse(xml)

    Comments= {}
    for comment in tree.xpath("//Boxes/Box"):
    #                                
        get_id = comment.attrib['Id']
        Comments[get_id] = []
        for group in comment.xpath(".//Tag"):
        #                        
            Comments[get_id].append(group.text)

    df_name1 = pd.DataFrame(dict([(k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in Comments.items()]))
```

Can anyone help to extract comments from XML file shown above? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is there a way to extract that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code given below:

```
def read_comments(xml):
    tree = etree.parse(xml)
    rows= []
    for box in tree.xpath('Box'):
        id = box.attrib['Id']
        tagTxt = box.findtext('Tag')
        if tagTxt is None:
            continue
        txtNode = etree.XML(tagTxt).find('Text')
        if txtNode is None:
            continue
        rows.append([id, txtNode.text.strip()])
    return pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['id', 'Comment'])
```

Note that if you create a DataFrame within a function, it is a **local**
variable of this function and is not visible from outside.
A better and more readable approach (as I did) is that the function **returns**
this DataFrame.

This function contains also *continue* in 2 places, to guard against possible
"error cases", when either *Box* element does not contain *Tag* child or
*Tag* does not contain any *Text* child element.

I also noticed that there is no need to replace `&lt;` or `&gt;` with `<` or
`>` with my own code, as *lxml* performs it on its own.

## Edit

My test is as follows: Start form imports:

```
import pandas as pd
from lxml import etree
```

I used a file containing:

```
<Boxes>
  <Box Id="3" ZIndex="13">
    <Shape>Rectangle</Shape>
    <Brush Id="0" />
    <Pen>
      <Color>#FF000000</Color>
    </Pen>
    <Tag>&lt;?xml version="1.0"?&gt;
&lt;PFDComment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;
  &lt;Text&gt;**EXAMPLE** &lt;/Text&gt;
&lt;/PFDComment&gt;</Tag>
  </Box>
</Boxes>
```

I called the above function:

```
df_name1 = read_comments('Boxes.xml')
```

and when I printed *df_name1*, I got:

```
  id      Comment
0  3  **EXAMPLE**
```

If something goes wrong, use the "extended" version of the above function,
with test printouts:

```
def read_comments(xml):
    tree = etree.parse(xml)
    rows= []
    for box in tree.xpath('Box'):
        id = box.attrib['Id']
        tagTxt = box.findtext('Tag')
        if tagTxt is None:
            print('No Tag element')
            continue
        txtNode = etree.XML(tagTxt).find('Text')
        if txtNode is None:
            print('No Text element')
            continue
        txt = txtNode.text.strip()
        print(f'{id}: {txt}')
        rows.append([id, txt])
    return pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['id', 'Comment'])
```

and take a look at printouts.